# Разбиение строки на подстроки используя массив разделителей в MS SQL 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Добрый день!

Имеется задачка по разбору почтового адреса в одной таблице и сопоставлению найденных составляющих адреса в другой таблице. Соответственно, возникла необходимость по вычленению некой сущности (в моём случае - номер квартиры) из строки, в которой имеются и другие данные.

Например, имеем следующий *разнообразнейший* набор строк, который содержит информацию о номере квартиры и комнаты (строки заполнены вручную оператором):

```
FLAT varchar
------------
12/1/3      --квартира 12, комнаты 1 и 3
134к3       --квартира 134, комната 3
12к.4       --квартира 12, комната 4
15k.2       --квартира 15, комната 2
21К4        --квартира 21, комната 4
27/а        --квартира 27а, но не квартира 27 комната А
27/2        --а это вот как раз 27-я квартира, и комната 2
24          --просто квартира 24, без комнат
25-6        --квартира 25, комната 6
23.1-3      --квартира 23, комнаты 1 и 3
90.к.2      --квартира 90, комната 2
71 комн.5   --квартира 71, комната 5
11в         --квартира 11в
```

Так как форматирование таких строк не соответствует какому-либо стандарту (и повлиять на это нет возможности - так приходят адреса из госструктуры одной), то было принято решение считать первое число в поле - номером квартиры, а всё последующее - относящимся к нумерации комнат.

При этом предполагается, что номера квартир и номера комнат будут сопоставляться с сущностями в другой таблице в полуавтоматическом режиме (сначала выделяем и ищем то, что можно выделить и найти, а остальное отдаем на сопоставление пользователю в ручном режиме).

Таким образом задача сводится к тому, что бы из подобного набора строк (изначально там несколько десятков тысяч записей) получить в одну колонку первое число, которое будет являться номером квартиры, и во второе поле - остаточную информацию (данные по комнатам).

Т.е. из исходной таблицы хотелось бы получить нечто такое:

```
FLAT varchar  F_NO varchar  ROOM_NO varchar
------------  ------------  ---------------
12/1/3        12            1/3
134к3         134           к3
12к.4         12            к.4
15            15            k.2
21К4          21            K4
27/а          27            А
27/2          27            2
24            24            (Null)
25-6          25            6
23.1-3        23            1-3
90.к.2        90            к.2
71 комн.5     71            комн.5
11в           11в           (Null)
```

Конечно, не плохо было бы далее распарсить поле ROOM_NO, вытащив и оттуда более-менее вменяемые номера комнат, но пока остановился хотя бы на номерах квартир.

Итак, сложность в том, что в качестве разделителя может использоваться обширный набор символов, от пробела и десятичной точки до слэшей, дефисов и некоторых букв.

Видел [реализации аналога](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23854724/6935496) [SUBSTRING_INDEX из MySQL](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) на англ. SO, но там функция (причем там несколько её реализаций) заточена под использование одного  разделителя, а если вызывать ее несколько раз для строки, перебирая массив разделителей, то что-то подсказывает мне, что это будет выполнятся очень неспешно...

Сейчас задачу решаю через 'REPLACE', примерно так же — применяя к строке 'REPLACE' для каждого разделителя (для получения квартиры). Примерно так:

```
...
CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX('@',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(_R2.Flat,
      '/','@'),
      '\','@'),
      'к','@'),
      'К','@'), --русская К
      '.','@'),
      ',','@'),
      ' ','@'),
      'k','@'),
      'K','@')  --английская K
    ) > 0)
    THEN LEFT(_R2.Flat,CHARINDEX('@',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(_R2.Flat,
      '/','@'),
      '\','@'),
      'к','@'),
      'К','@'), --русская К
      '.','@'),
      ',','@'),
      ' ','@'),
      'k','@'),
      'K','@')  --английская K
    ) - 1)
    ELSE ISNULL(_R2.Flat,'0')
  END --CASE
```

Разумеется, такой вариант тоже не очень-то нравится (громоздкий, не универсальный, не учитывает комнаты, не очень быстрый...).

И вот что-то подсказывает мне, что я далеко не первый из сообщества, кто сталкивался с разбором подобных адресов и строк в принципе, потому буду признателен за любые рекомендации, советы, код и всё то, что помогло бы решить задачу.

Заранее благодарен за внимание и с Наступающим! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот как разбить по разным символам, где @c - имя вашего поля. В квадратные скобки перечисляются символы по которым разбивать (минус и процент - служебные, остальные без проблем)

```
select     case when @c like '%[:,.;A-Zа-zА-Яа-я]%' then
    substring(@c,1, patindex('%[:,.;A-Zа-zА-Яа-я]%',@c)-1) else @c end , 
           case when @c like '%[:,.;A-Zа-zА-Яа-я]%' then 
       substring(@c,patindex('%[:,.;A-Zа-zА-Яа-я]%',@c),255) else null end
```

Если оставить только цифры, можно с отрицанием так (по совету **Mike**):

```
select     case when @c like '%[^0-9]%' then
    substring(@c,1, patindex('%[^0-9]%',@c)-1) else @c end , 
           case when @c like '%[^0-9]%' then 
       substring(@c,patindex('%[^0-9]%',@c),255) else null end
```

p.s.  255 - это привычка из старого паскаля, наверно 99 достаточно. Но если строка длинне этого числа то нужно 8000 ставить (длиннее mssql не позволяет строки делать) либо `len(@c)`.

Comment: Зачем так страшно то. Может проще `PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',a)`

Comment: Не знал что есть отрицание... класс

Comment: Про отрицание, паттерны LIKE, о паттернах в PATINDEX я знал по отдельности, но вот это не очень помогло )))
Спасибо за ответ и комментарии к нему!